# highlight table data based on winner values obtained from JSON

Tags: css, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-bind

I am parsing JSON data and displaying the data to a table using angular JS.

There are many table rows that I populated from JSON file using `ng-repeat`.

`Status.winner` could be of values 0 or 1.

If the value for the winner for the table row is 0, I would like to highlight  `Playerdata[0].playername` for that table row to yellow color.

Else If the winner for the table row is 1, then I would like to highlight `Playerdata[1].playername` for that table row  to yellow color.

How do I do that for each row with different values of winner, which can be 0 or 1?

```
<body ng-app="form-input" ng-controller="ctrl">
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed ">
  <caption>Recent Game Statistic</caption>
  <tbody> 
  <tr class="success"  ng-repeat="status in recentGame">      
    <td ng-bind="status.Winner"> </td> 
    <td ng-bind="status.Playerdata[0].Playername"> </td> 
    <td ng-bind="status.Playerdata[1].Playername"> </td> 
  </tr>
```

```
var app2 = angular.module('form-input', []);

app2.controller('ctrl', function($scope,$http) { 

var url = "http://...JSON";

$http.get(url).success( function(data) { 
  $scope.recentGame = data.RecentGames; 
  });   
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ngClass:

```
<tr class="success" ng-repeat="status in recentGame">      
    <td ng-bind="status.Winner"></td> 
    <td ng-bind="status.Playerdata[0].Playername" ng-class="{winner: status.Winner == 0}"></td> 
    <td ng-bind="status.Playerdata[1].Playername" ng-class="{winner: status.Winner == 1}"></td> 
</tr>
```

Then in CSS define `.winner` class styles the way you need. For example:

```
.winner {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: I thought it works, but it is actually highlighting the entire row, and for the record where the winner is no 1, both player data[1] and data[0] values was highlighted. Is there a way to highlight only the td for the winner?

Comment: You are doing something wrong, should work http://plnkr.co/edit/4gN3qFvcX8VYRsmQ5jzm?p=preview

Comment: oh okay. I mistakenly put the ng-class on the tr. Thank you.

Comment: Hi can you please help me, if you don't mind, I have an additional question. Do you know how to change the character code in the html table to a character name based on $scope.character object, which is added at plunk app.js?. Example, for player character in table row 1 , would like to change the word from 4 to Luna, 6 to Harland. I am really new in angularJS, and learning it. http://plnkr.co/edit/izUO1W6g8vUGRB6ILV3k?p=preview

Comment: `$scope.character` structure is not very convenient for this. Can you change  the structure of it or it is fixed?